# Getting "You are trying to import a file after the Jest environment has been torn down" and "right-hand side of instanceof is not callable" in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jestjs

I'm trying to test a mongodb application but jest is throwing some errors my way
here's the code for the file i'm testing
I inserted a dummy function: testFunct() that just returns one for sanity purposes

```
const User = require("./database/database.js");
const client = require("./twitch/twitch.js");
const chalk = require("chalk");

var peopleWatching = new Object();

client.on("join", (channel, username, self) => {
  if (!self) {
    newUser(username);
  }
});

client.on("message", (channel, user, message, self) => {
  var name = user["display-name"];

  if (peopleWatching[name]) {
    peopleWatching[name].messagesSent++;
  } else {
    newUser(name);
  }
});

client.on("part", (channel, name, self) => {
  if (peopleWatching[name]) {
    data = peopleWatching[name];

    updateUser(data, name);
  } else {
    console.log(
      chalk.black.bgKeyword("darkorange")("WARN") +
        " untracked user " +
        chalk.underline(name) +
        " left the channel"
    );
  }
});

async function newUser(name) {
  var newUser = new User({ uName: name });
  await newUser
    .save()
    .then((val) => {
      console.log(
        chalk.black.bgGreen("NEW") +
          " " +
          chalk.underline(name) +
          " " +
          chalk.green("Has been added to the database")
      );
    })
    .catch(async (err) => {
      console.log(
        chalk.bgRed("ERR!") +
          ` ${chalk.underline(name)} already in the database`
      );
      newUser = await User.findOne({ uName: name });
    });

  if (!peopleWatching[name]) {
    peopleWatching[name] = {
      user: newUser,
      timeJoined: Date.now() / 1000,
      messagesSent: 0,
    };
  } else {
    // This person already exists
  }
}

async function updateUser(data, name) {
  user = data.user;
  messages = data.messagesSent;
  timeWatched = (Date.now() / 1000 - data.timeJoined)/60;

  user.messagesSent += messages;
  user.timeWatched += timeWatched;
  user.save();
  peopleWatching[name] = undefined;
  console.log(
    chalk.black.bgCyan("UPD") +
      " " +
      chalk.underline(name) +
      " " +
      chalk.green("Has been updated")
  );
}

function testFunct(){
    return 1;
}

module.exports = {testFunct,updateUser,newUser}
```

and the code for the test. currently i'm only testing my dummy function

```
const {testFunct,updateUser,newUser} = require('./index.js')
const jestConfig = require('./jest.config.js')

jest.useFakeTimers()
test("First test",()=>{
    expect(testFunct()).toBe(1)
})
```

and finally, the output from npm run test

```
npm run test

> kamibot@1.0.0 test C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot
> jest

 PASS  ./index.test.js
  √ First test (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.188 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites.

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at BufferList.Readable (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:179:22)
      at BufferList.Duplex (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
      at new BufferList (node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
      at new MessageStream (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
      at new Connection (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:54:28)
C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:111
  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex;
                        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
    at new ReadableState (C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:111:25)
    at BufferList.Readable (C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:183:25)
    at BufferList.Duplex (C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
    at new BufferList (C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\bl\bl.js:33:16)
    at new MessageStream (C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:35:21)
    at new Connection (C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:54:28)
    at C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:36:29
    at callback (C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:280:5)
    at Socket.connectHandler (C:\Users\brand\repos\kamiBot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:325:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1127:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! kamibot@1.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the kamibot@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\brand\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-26T13_46_29_769Z-debug.log
```

I made sure to read the mongoose documentation and I made sure to configure jest.config.js just like the docs said to

Comment: You didn't provide the rest of modules in use. Considering that you don't use anything async from index.js, they clearly do asynchronous side effects that end later than the test.

Comment: thanks! so if i'm understanding correctly, i have to import index.js' dependencies as well?

Comment: No, you need to prevent asynchronous processes that occur there, or or chain them in the test, so it doesn't end (or start) until these processes are completed. And you need to list them in the question if you need assistance with your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did some digging and it looks like the errors show up when i include my "database.js" which includes the mongoose.connect() function which seems to be causing the problem. Since that function is asynchronous it's causing problems for jest. I'm not entirely sure how I can cause it to run synchronously because node yells at me if I try to use await for mongoose.connect()

Comment: Yells what? You shouldn't call it twice, in case you did it. Mongoose connection is chained internally by queries and usually doesn't need to be awaited. Just await queries. You shouldn't import db-related files in tests where you don't use db, like you did. And you need to have `await mongoose.connection.close()` in `afterAll`. Btw `updateUser(data, name)` and `newUser(username)` will be quite difficult to test because you use callbacks and don't have a promise to chain. Better to mock `database` completely to test `client` events.

Comment: I moved stuff around in my application so now all the functions I want to test are independent of the database connection. Inside of the test file I can connect to a test database and await for the connection and disconnection in beforeall and afterall

Answer (score 0):

Being older and wiser, I now understand that we should avoid side-effects in unit tests. Instead, we should stub functions that have side effects (like network, database or filesystem) using a library like `sinon`